# Dynamically switch app engine based on URL express

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, express

How Do I set App Engine based on URL ?

I got two render engine for my application, `serverSideRenderEngine`  & `browserRenderEngine`

If, url is `/home` `app.engine` should be set as `serverSideRenderEngine`

If, url is `/login` `app.engine` should be set as `browserRenderEngine`

Current for all url's, I'm setting my app.engine to `browserRenderEngine`

Below is my app engine code,

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', distFolder);
app.engine('html', browserRenderEngine) // it set to browserRenderEngine by default;
```

So how do I switch based on URL ? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a middleware like :

```
 app.use((req, res, next) => {
    // check the url
    if(req.originalUrl.startsWith('/home')  ) {
        app.engine('html', serverSideRenderEngine) 
     }
    else {
        app.engine('html', browserRenderEngine) 
    }
    next();
});
```